# Is it possible to run a Postgres Database as a Docker container and backup it periodically to a NAS?

Tags: postgresql, windows, docker, backup, nas

I am struggeling to get this working. It is no problem for me to set up a Postgres Database with Docker and acess it from other clients with Dbeaver or PGAdmin. My problem is, I am not able to perform an automatic backup of the docker container or volume.

This is my Docker Compose file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  db:
    container_name: imatecTest
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      POSTGRES_DB: test
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin4
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "5050:80
```

The only way it "worked" was this:
I saved the volume of the docker container locally in my windows directory and did my backup with windows-backup. The problem is I have to shut down my database during the backup otherwise there will be data loss.

Can you give me some advice how to perform an automatic backup of my volume or the whole container with PG_Dump or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally you can use **pg_dump** command to backup your postgres database

```
pg_dump -U postgres -h localhost -f <BACKUP_FILE> <DATABASE_NAME>
```

additionally Use a tool like **rsync** to copy the backup file to the NAS device. You can use a cron job to schedule the backup process to run periodically.

Hope it helps

Comment: Does it work the same way with Docker running on Windows?

Comment: these tools should work or you might need to investigate other flavours of rsync